# Make google-chrome browser go fullscreen when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, browser

**Please consider answering this question here even if you mark it as a duplicate** because for some reason I just can't get it to work with other solutions and though I tried to ask for help no one replied...

What I really want is to `$(document).ready(function(){browser goes fullscreen})` but unfortunately it isn't working and I am desperate through trying to find a solution online because nothing appears to work! I have the js file well inserted in my main php file (console.log works) but it just won't load fullscreen no matter the lines of code...

If you can provide a solution to work in all browsers and **with keys activated** I would be really, really thankful. Otherwise I'll contempt myself with the google chrome answer. Thank you so much.

EDIT1:

I tried this

```
// mozilla proposal
element.requestFullScreen();
document.cancelFullScreen(); 

// Webkit (works in Safari and Chrome Canary)
element.webkitRequestFullScreen(); 
document.webkitCancelFullScreen(); 

// Firefox (works in nightly)
element.mozRequestFullScreen();
document.mozCancelFullScreen(); 

// W3C Proposal
element.requestFullscreen();
document.exitFullscreen();
```

The following one only under user interaction:

```
addEventListener("click", function() {
    var
          el = document.documentElement
        , rfs =
               el.requestFullScreen
            || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
            || el.mozRequestFullScreen
    ;
    rfs.call(el);
});
```

amongst others I can't find now and basically I have combined them with `$(document).ready(function(){---});` but nothing happened.

Comment: please provide some code for us to investigate why it fails.

Comment: For security reasons you might find that actions such as "full-screen" might only be available if they are enacted as a direct result of a user action i.e. "click".

Comment: @Gotschi I have no code at the moment, I have ran over so much attempts and switch things that I don't know which one to put here but I'll edit the question and try to go over this if it helps.

Comment: I don't believe you can go fullscreen on page load.  The user must initiate this action.  Could you imagine the fullscreen popup windows all over the Internet if this would be allowed to happen without the user explicitly initiating it?

Comment: @DeanTaylor Ty for the tip Dean but I was actually aware of this and it isn't the problem... Code that described this feature didn't work and the same happened to code made to "force" the fullscreen.

Comment: @HaukurHaf I see what you mean, but why couldn't I? I have a markup $document.ready that basically tells me "on ready do this" and could be any line of code, it just tells the javascript interpreter to begin acting I guess... and If I happen to be wrong then it would be fairly easy to simulate a button "click here because" and after pop up fullscreen.

Comment: @user3050963 provide a sample code which you have tried and is not working - include specific details like browsers tested etc.

Comment: @DeanTaylor I tested them in google-chrome, as tagged in the question

Comment: @user3050963, no it literally cannot be any line of code.  The browser is fully capable of allowing certain things and preventing other things.

Comment: @user3050963 Browsers are allowed to refuse to perform an action if the browser deems it a security risk, such as only allowing you to initiate fullscreen if the code doing it is within a click event handler.

Comment: Check the debug console for warning messages

Comment: @DeanTaylor No warning messages. I understand what you mean obviously but I was thinking they wouldn't really do that when it's easy to trick the user into making it fullscreen. Can you provide me proper code to propose the user to go fullscreen? Just to make the top-bar (in chrome) appear and saying "the website is asking you to go fullscreen" and actually check if they accepted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The short answer is you can't.**

I have tested using [this code](https://gist.github.com/DeanMarkTaylor/7921880).

In Firefox is outputs this warning in the console - frankly I was expecting this kind of warning from all browsers, however it seems currently only Firefox implements this.

```
Request for full-screen was denied because Element.mozRequestFullScreen() was not called from inside a short running user-generated event handler.
```

As I stated in my comment:

> For security reasons you might find that actions such as "full-screen"
>   might only be available if they are enacted as a direct result of a
>   user action i.e. "click"

Well it's true.
Get the user to click something (or take some other user event) to make then call the full-screen functions.

Browsers Tested (navigator.userAgent):

- **Chrome 31**: `"5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36"`
- **Firefox 25**: `"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"`
- **IE 11**: `"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; rv:11.0) like Gecko"`